# Erro no bouncycastle readObject() - Demoiselle-certificate

Tags: demoiselle, demoiselle-certificate

Estou utilizando o Demoiselle-certificate(2.0.0) há algum tempo e hoje me deparei com o seguinte erro quando chamada a classe CertificateManager o método certificateManager.load(class):

```
10:35:07,632 GRAVE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-5) org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;
```

O erro é por não encontrar o método  `org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()`

```
        Caused by: org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;
                at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(InterceptorInvocationContext.java:151) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
                at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.exception.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.manage(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:239) [demoiselle-core-2.5.0.jar:]
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor173.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_79]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
                at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorInvocation$InterceptorMethodInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:72) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:82) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:133) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:112) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:53) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
                at br.com.djcloud.view.EmpresaManutencaoEditMB$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.validarCertificado(EmpresaManutencaoEditMB$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.java) [classes:]
                at br.com.djcloud.view.EmpresaManutencaoEditMB$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.validarCertificado(EmpresaManutencaoEditMB$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
                at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
                at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
                at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
                at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
                at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
                ... 36 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;
                at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.oid.OIDGeneric.getInstance(OIDGeneric.java:80) [demoiselle-certificate-core-2.0.0.jar:]
                at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.extension.CertificateExtra.<init>(CertificateExtra.java:98) [demoiselle-certificate-core-2.0.0.jar:]
                at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.extension.ICPBRSubjectAlternativeNames.<init>(ICPBRSubjectAlternativeNames.java:56) [demoiselle-certificate-core-2.0.0.jar:]
                at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.extension.BasicCertificate.getICPBRSubjectAlternativeNames(BasicCertificate.java:286) [demoiselle-certificate-core-2.0.0.jar:]
                at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.extension.BasicCertificate.hasCertificatePF(BasicCertificate.java:313) [demoiselle-certificate-core-2.0.0.jar:]
                at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.extension.ICPBrasilExtensionLoader.load(ICPBrasilExtensionLoader.java:58) [demoiselle-certificate-core-2.0.0.jar:]
                at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.CertificateManager.load(CertificateManager.java:110) [demoiselle-certificate-core-2.0.0.jar:]
                at br.com.djsystem.seguranca.util.DJCertImpl.lerArquivo(DJCertImpl.java:195) [classes:]
                at br.com.djcloud.view.EmpresaManutencaoEditMB.validarCertificado(EmpresaManutencaoEditMB.java:335) [classes:]
                at br.com.djcloud.view.EmpresaManutencaoEditMB$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.validarCertificado(EmpresaManutencaoEditMB$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.java) [classes:]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
                at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:114) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
                at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(InterceptorInvocationContext.java:143) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
                ... 56 more
```

Se alguém já passou por isso, está passando ou tem alguma ideia do que pode ser, por gentileza, agradeço a atenção.

edit: aplicação utilizando certificado instalado:

```
 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    setCert((java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate"));
    CertificateManager cm = new CertificateManager(getCert()[0], isValidarCert());
    setCertificadoString(getCert()[0].toString());
    cm.load(this);
```

Aplicação com arquivo:

```
        KeyStore keyStore = (new FileSystemKeyStoreLoader(file)).getKeyStore(senhaCertificado.trim());

        Enumeration<?> enumeration = keyStore.aliases();
        String alias = (String) enumeration.nextElement();

        x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
    CertificateManager cm = new CertificateManager(x509Certificate , false);
    cm.load(this);
```

Comment: Olá Michel, desculpe a demora em responder, mas estive com problemas particulares a resolver esses dias. Tem como incluir o POM.XML também? Ou até quem sabe compartilhar (github) o projeto ou parte dele que está gerando o erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao realizar os testes com a versão **2.0.1-SNAPSHOT** foi verificado que o mesmo erro continua acontecendo.

Ao realizar um debug mais apurado, comparando as versões 1.0.9 (Versão que não ocorre o problema) e as versões mais recentes (2.0.0 e 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT), foi identificado onde o erro ocorre. Abaixo segue os detalhes:

Em uma classe de implementação própria, é realizada uma instância da classe *CertificateManager* e é chamado o método load.

```
CertificateManager cm = new CertificateManager(arqx509, false);
cm.load(this);
```

Após isso, é executado o método load do *CertificateManager*

```
public void load(Object object) {
    Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        for (Annotation annotation : field.getAnnotations()) {
            if (annotation.annotationType().isAnnotationPresent(OIDExtension.class)) {
                OIDExtension oid = annotation.annotationType().getAnnotation(OIDExtension.class);

                Class<? extends IOIDExtensionLoader> loaderClass = oid.loader();
                try {
                    IOIDExtensionLoader loader = loaderClass.newInstance();
                    loader.load(object, field, x509);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
                    throw new CertificateCoreException("Error: Could not initialize atribute \"" + field.getName() + "\"", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Em seguida, a classe *CertificateManager* realizada uma chamada para o método load para da classe *IOIDExtensionLoader*, conforme abaixo:

```
IOIDExtensionLoader loader = loaderClass.newInstance();
loader.load(object, field, x509);
```

Em seguida é encaminhada a ação para o método load da classe *ICPBrasilExtensionLoader*, que é quem faz a implementação da *IOIDExtensionLoader*. Ao realizar o debug, foi verificado que antes de entrar no `switch (annotation.type()) {`, é criada uma instância da classe *BasicCertificate*, passando como parâmetro o arquivo x509, conforme abaixo:

```
 @Override
public void load(Object object, Field field, X509Certificate x509) {
    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ICPBrasilExtension.class)) {
        ICPBrasilExtension annotation = field.getAnnotation(ICPBrasilExtension.class);

        Object keyValue;
        try {

            BasicCertificate cert = new BasicCertificate(x509); <-- AQUI

            switch (annotation.type()) {
                case CPF:
                    if (cert.hasCertificatePF()) {
                        keyValue = cert.getICPBRCertificatePF().getCPF();
                    } else {
                        keyValue = "";
                    }
```

Visto que na versão 1.0.9 essa instância é criada sem problemas, porém na versão 2.0.0 ela é criada mas mostra uma notificação de que foi lançada uma exception, conforme pode ser visto abaixo:

**Versão 1.0.9**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]


**Versão 2.0.0**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa maneira ao realizar a leitura da linha `if (cert.hasCertificatePF()) {` ocorre a exception.

Answer (score 0):

A impressão é que está faltando a lib bcprov-jdk15on ou que a mesma possa estar corrompida.
O erro é quando executa a Applet? Se for, neste caso precisa conferir se a lib bcprov-jdk51on ela está em /src/main/webapp/ e que esteja assinada corretamente.

Comment: Até alguns dias funcionava, ele processava o certificado, extraía os dados numa classe, conforme a documentação do demoiselle, mas de repente não funcionou mais... O erro ocorre quando o método certificateManager.load(class) é chamado. Vou anexar o pom, ou carregar parte do projeto... Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Inseri conforme orientou a dependência, mas o erro persiste, quem faz a leitura do certificado, é o demoiselle-certificate, uso a versão 2.0.0... Percebi que o erro ocorreu após os problemas no sourceforge....

Comment: Pode ser que depois do problema no sourceforge, tenha acontecido algum problema e tenha corrompido a sua lib. Mas vc ainda não confirmou se está ocorrendo o problema quando executa uma Applet? Com uma parte do código é possível tentar reproduzir o erro.

Comment: Sim o mesmo problema ocorre em Applet... Testei também utilizando um novo projeto web a partir do demoiselle, em nossa aplicação utilizamos o método de duas formas, uma delas carregando o arquivo pelo upload do primefaces, abrindo-o com a senha e em seguida lendo-o com o certificateManager e outra utilização é recebendo o certificado instalado no navegador do cliente, através do HttpServletRequest, e ambas devolvem o mesmo erro. Vou colocar na pergunta trexos do código de como utilizamos os métodos.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez a atenção, Saito!

Comment: Você já chegou a apagar as libs do repositório local? E ainda faltou colocar o POM.XML, mas de qualquer forma experimente usar a versão 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT do componente.  Assim poderá verificar se o problema é da versão Para isso vc precisa configurar o repositório:       <repository>
   <id>demoiselle.sourceforge.net-snapshot</id>
   <url>http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/repository/snapshot</url>
  </repository>

Comment: Olá Saito, fiz uma aplicação de teste utilizando o exemplo do estacionamento para que você possa verificar o que ocorre. É necessário apenas logar, pois coloquei a leitura do certificado na tela principal. Lá é necessário selecionar o certificado, carregar. Após isso insira a senha e clique no botão validar. Dessa maneira o erro ocorrerá. Percebi que tirando a dependência  do jasperReport o erro não ocorre mais, então não sei o que pode estar acontecendo. Segue o link para download da aplicação de exemplo: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8h80qc6y1go5wv0/%40Certificado.zip?dl=0 . Obrigado.